# Is $K$ bounded? Is there a $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

I have two questions, but I don't know if they're true. I couldn't develop a reasoning for these sentences.

If $X$ is a relatively compact subset ($\overline{X}$ is compact) of $\ell_1$, is $X$ bounded?

My attempt is:

If $\overline{X}$ is compact, then for a sequence $(a_n)$ of $\overline{X}$, exists $\mathbb{N}_1\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}a_n=a\in\overline{X}.$$

So:

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}_1;  \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}a_n=a\in\overline{X}\Rightarrow ||a||_p=||\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}a_n||_p=\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}||a_n||_p=\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
But I couldn't find a north.

Another questions is:

For a arbitrary positive $\varepsilon$, is there a $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\underset{(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\in X}{\sup}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq n_\varepsilon}|a_n|\right)\leq \varepsilon\text{ }?$$

PS: $\ell_1$ is a sequence space such that:

$$\ell_n=\left\{(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty};a_i\in\mathbb{K}, \forall i\in\mathbb{N} \text{ and }\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|^n<\infty\right\},$$

where $\mathbb{K}$ is the scalar space. Also, the norm $||\cdot||_n$ is given by

$$||(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}||_n=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

Comment: boundedness holds in any metric space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What do you mean?

Comment: Any relatively compact subset of a metric space is bounded. Nothing special about $\ell_1$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I got it. Do you know somewhere I can see this result? :)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I got the first part. But is the seconde true?